# AngularJS: Trying to clean up an API Feed by processing $http response is not working

Tags: angularjs

I have an API Feed of global variables to be used throughout an application. The raw feed looks like this:

```
[
  {
    id: "1",
    var: "g_crop_year",
    val: "2015"
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    var: "g_season",
    val: "F"
  }
]
```

To me, that is awkward to work with throughout an application and I would prefer it look like this:

```
[
  { g_crop_year: "2015" },
  { g_season: "F" }
]
```

I tried this:

```
$http.get('/globals')
     .success(function(globals){
         var simpleGlobals = [];
         for(var g=0; g<globals.length;g++){
            var glo = {
               globals[g].var: globals[g].val
             };
             simpleGlobals.push(glo);
          }
          $scope.globals = simpleGlobals;
      });
```

My thoughts were to loop through the returned data, create the structure I want and push to a new array which I assign to $scope. But I am wrong. I get a blank page and an unexpected token in the `globals[g].var: globals[g].val` line.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This is not the right approach to create your designated approach.

```
    var glo = {
       globals[g].var: globals[g].val
     };
```

The string **globals[g].var** is actually being considered as the key rather than interpreting it as a value.

You should instead create a blank object first and then use the array annotation to assign a particular value to the key.

```
    var glo = {};
    glo[globals[g].var] = globals[g].val;
```

Comment: That is literally the same answer as mine.

Comment: I was typing mine while your answer was posted. I, by no means, tried to replicate it .. Anyways, apologies for mistakingly replicating it.

Answer (score 3):

This will not work as you expect:

```
        var glo = {
           globals[g].var: globals[g].val
         };
```

They key of the `glo` object is attempting be the literal text `globals[g].var`; change that, instead, to:

```
        var glo = {};
        glo[globals[g].var] = globals[g].val;
```

As a side note, you may want to assign to `$rootScope` or a Service to make these globals available to all of your controllers.